# Why teamcity can't show svn Changes in text diff view?

Tags: svn, teamcity, teamcity-6

I have following exception in `http://teamcity_server/diffView.html?....`

```
ERROR:
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: connection refused by the server
svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/path'
```

it strange because Teamcity agents correctly updates projects from svn and site correctly shows changed files.

Comment: This is your first time setting up teamcity?

Comment: @Bragboy: Can't fathom how your comment is actually supposed to help the OP (or anyone). Perhaps you can expand on it?

Comment: Yura, this looks like a bug. Please write about the problem to TeamCity forum at http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/teamcity/teamcity?view=discussions . Please include your VCS log from TeamCity/logs/teamcity-vcs.log